# Decrypting a Video For Video Playback Xamarin.Forms

Tags: .net, cryptography, xamarin.forms

So I've been using a Xamarin component that implements Video Playback. It allows System.IO.Streams to be played as source and I've had no problem creating these from a byte[]. I've been trying to use System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream but have been unable to implement it as a source. I'd like to decrypt my byte[] for the video player 'On The Fly' if possible.

Comment: For extra info: Padding Mode, PKCS7; CipherMode, CBC (will be changing to ECB)

Comment: Would you mind if I ask what component are you using for video playback from stream? Does it also support mp3 audio files?

Comment: Is it this? https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer